# Asynchronous programming and interrupts exception handlers

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, exception, operating-system

I'm new to programming, just a question on how asynchronous programming actually works.
We know that interrupts occur asynchronously as a result of signals from I/O devices that are
external to the processor. So for example, when the processor has finished executing an instruction, and the processor notices that the interrupt pin has gone high (e.g network adapter notify there is data coming), reads the exception number from the system bus, and then calls the appropriate interrupt handler. When the handler returns, it returns control to the next instruction. 
So it needs hardware support. (a dedicated pin allocated to I/O)
so how can asynchronous programming work without hardware support, how the operating systems sends "notification" of'Hi the result is ready, come and get it" to current process. 
From my understanding, without hardware support, we can only achieve it by multithread or multiprocess.

Comment: multithreading (at least, the common pre-emptive style) also uses an interrupt -- specifically, a timer-interrupt that gets raised when the current quantum is up and it's time for the scheduler to choose another thread to execute for the next quantum.

Answer (score 1):

> So it needs hardware support. (a dedicated pin allocated to I/O) so how can asynchronous programming work without hardware support, how the operating systems sends "notification" of'Hi the result is ready, come and get it" to current process. From my understanding, without hardware support, we can only achieve it by multithread or multiprocess.

Understand that (in general) there's many layers separated by (often intentionally abstract) interfaces. From lowest level to highest level these layers might be:

- hardware interface to platform facilities (e.g. interrupt controller built into the chipset)
- hardware interfaces for various types of devices
- abstract device driver interfaces
- the kernel's API
- a language "run-time" (e.g. maybe a shared library or libraries, but maybe a virtual machine like Java's virtual machine)
- the program generated by tools (e.g. compilers, linkers)
- the developer's source code

Throughout all these layers of stuff there's (beneficial) lies and trickery. You might think you set variable X to the value 123, but the compiler decided to optimise the code and do something else. You might think you received a notification from the OS, but the notification actually came from language's run-time and the OS never sent it. You might think the notification re-started a thread but threads are a big lie from someone (possibly compiler, possibly run-time, possibly kernel).

To figure out the exact mechanics of how asynchronous notifications works and what it really is at all the different layers; you need to know a lot more information about the specific scenario (which notification for which version of which language compiled by which compiler with which settings running on which OS on top of which architecture/hardware).